# How to increase the distance between the columns in the legend Core plot pieChart

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, pie-chart

I want to have 2 columns legend under the diagram, and I would like that they are on the sides of the screen, not on the left.
This how it's look like now:
[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Core Plot legends have many options to customize the layout, including the size of the color swatch, the spacing between rows and columns, and the number of rows and/or columns in the grid. See [the `CPTLegend` docs](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_legend.html) for the details.

The legend itself is just a `CPTLayer` (Core Animation `CALayer` subclass). The Core Plot graph provides convenience properties for positioning the legend ([`legendAnchor`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_graph.html#a6e97cebb8d0cff47d7c22b47e02798c8) and [`legendDisplacement`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/group__graph_animation.html#ga262aa2db69e5e4438f8542762f0e1d85)). If these don't provide enough control, you can position the legend layer anywhere you want using annotations. Use a layer annotation to tie the location to a specific graph layer (fixed screen position) or a plot space annotation so it moves with the plot data.

Answer (score 0):

It's done only just by one line of code:   `theLegend.columnMargin = 90.0;`
 Or `theLegend.columnWidths = arrOfWidths;`